Is any way to run tensorflow-gpu 2.2.0 with RTX4090 or RTX 3070
I want to try to run a docker image on my computer. This container image is the Tensorflow-gpu image officially packaged by Nvidia. Since the code I want to run must use tensorflow2.2 and requires cuda 10, I can only choose This image, but I found that running this image on my computer is very slow, and even prompts for an unsupported graphics card type when starting the image. I guess it may be due to a driver problem on my computer, because I can use the host's graphics card normally on a Tasle T4 machine with the same image, but the driver for that machine is:
Driver Version: 470.129.06 CUDA Version: 11.4
My new host uses rtx3070 and it seems that there is no suitable 470.x graphics card driver. My current driver version is Driver Version: 535.171.04 and cuda 11.7. I have tried many methods but can't solve this problem. Can anyone help me? Thank
I want this image to run properly on my host

In other words, if I want to use TensorFlow-GPU 2.2.0 officially packaged by Nvidia. Do I have to use the 470.x version driver? But the RTX 4090 doesn't have 470.x driver . How to deal with this situation?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am sorry my little english.
I want to use this image nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:19.10-py3 with RTX 3070, but it can not work.
OS Info:Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Nvidia Driver Version: 535.171.04
cuda toolkit Version: 11.7
